# Join a line to its preceding

Tags: join, vim, line

It often happens when I am at the front of a line and I wish to join this line to its preceding line. Usually I have to go to the end of the preceding line and then press J to achieve it. I just wonder if there is an easier way.

Comment: You don't have to be at the end of the line. Just `kJ`. If you really want (and don't use `K` to look up man pages), you could remap that - `:nmap K kJ`. But I think that's a bit of overkill to save a single keystroke.

Comment: @Kevin write an answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Join plugin](https://github.com/sk1418/Join), can do exactly what you want. It supports negative counts.  In your case, you give `:J -1` . You can of course do `:J -10` to join 10 lines backwards.

Except for the negative counts, it supports more features, like, join with separator, reverse join, join and keep lines ... check the plugin page for detailed feature and screenshots.

The script was written by me.

Comment: Or use Vim's native `:join` with a negative range. e.g. `:-j`